# PHP array_walk() in class with multiple arguments

Tags: php, class, array-walk

Good day,

I got the following issue.
Have a method in a class that I want to call with *array_walk* with two arguments.

```
array_walk($fields, array($this, 'SetAlias'), $Table);
```

When I put a comment in the method *SetAlias()* it does respond. Hence it is being called.

**The method being called is:**

```
private function SetAlias($value, $table){
    if(isset($this->alias[$table][$value]) === true){
            $value = $value.'` AS `'.$this->alias[$table][$value];
    }
    return($value);
}
```

**Arguments**

But when I print the function arguments it returns :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => parking_id
        [1] => 0
        [2] => parking
    )
```

Unfortunately this is not working for me.

So I COULD change the method's arguments to:

```
private function SetAlias($value, $null, $table){
```

Still no results.

**The code**:

```
<?php

class Test {
    public  $fields                     =   array('parking' => array('parking_id', 'parking_country', 'parking_name'));
    public  $alias                          =   array();



    private function SetAlias($value, $table){
        if(isset($this->alias[$table][$value]) === true){
                $value = $value.'` AS `'.$this->alias[$table][$value];
        }
        return($value);
    }


    public function GetFields($Table){
        $fields = $this->fields[$Table];

        if(isset($this->alias[$Table]) === true){
            array_walk($fields, array($this, 'SetAlias'), $Table);
        }

        return('`'.implode($fields, '`, `').'`');
    }

}





$example = new Test();
$example->alias['parking'] = array('parking_id'=>'id', 'parking_country'=>'country');

echo $example->GetFields('parking');
?>
```

It currently returns:

**`parking_id`, `parking_country`, `parking_name`**

What am I missing?

**Works *by VolkerK***

```
public function GetFields($table){
    $fields = $this->fields[$table];

    if(isset($this->alias[$table]) === true) {
        $fn = function($e) use ($table) {
            return $this->SetAlias($e, $table);
        };
        $fn = $fn->BindTo($this);
        $fields = array_map( $fn, $fields );
    }

    return('`'.implode($fields, '`, `').'`');
}
```

> Does not work in a static context though. Is it possible to make this
>   work?
>
> ```
> $fn = $fn->BindTo(__CLASS__);
> $SetFields = array_map( $fn, $SetFields );
> ```
>
> - *Warning: Closure::bindTo() expects parameter 1 to be object, string    given*

**Static context**

```
<?php

class Test {
    public static $fields                           =   array('parking' => array('parking_id', 'parking_country', 'parking_name'));
    public static $alias                            =   array();

    private static function SetAlias($value, $table){
        if(isset(self::$alias[$table][$value]) === true){
            $value = $value.'` AS `'.self::$alias[$table][$value];
        }
        return($value);
    }


    public static function GetFields($table){
        $fields = self::$fields[$table];

        if(isset(self::$alias[$table]) === true) {
            $fn = function($e) use ($table) {
                return self::SetAlias($e, $table);
            };
            $fn = $fn->BindTo(__CLASS__);
            $fields = array_map( $fn, $fields );
        }

        return('`'.implode($fields, '`, `').'`');
    }
}





Test::$alias['parking'] = array('parking_id'=>'id', 'parking_country'=>'country');

echo Test::GetFields('parking');
?>
```

> **WORKS *VolkerK*:**
>
> ```
>  <?php
> class Test {
>     public static $fields   = array('parking' => array('parking_id', 'parking_country', 'parking_name'));
>     public static $alias    = array();
>
>     private static function SetAlias($value, $table){
>         if(isset($table[$value]) === true){
>             $value = $value.'` AS `'.$table[$value];
>         }
>         return($value);
>     }
>
>     protected static function getFieldMapper($table) {
>         if( !isset(self::$alias[$table]) ) {
>             return function($e) { return $e; };
>         }
>
>         $table = self::$alias[$table];
>         return function($e) use ($table) {
>             return Test::SetAlias($e, $table);
>         };
>     }
>
>     public static function GetFields($table){
>         $fields = array_map( self::getFieldMapper($table), self::$fields[$table]);
>         return('`'.implode($fields, '`, `').'`');
>     }
> }
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_walk returns a boolean and it doesn't alter the input array, so you won't get the values from SetAlias() back into GetFields() this way.
But you can use [aray_map()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead.

```
<?php
class Test {
    public  $fields = array('parking' => array('parking_id', 'parking_country', 'parking_name'));
    public  $alias  = array();

    private function SetAlias($value, $table) {
        if(isset($this->alias[$table][$value]) === true){
            $value = $value.'` AS `'.$this->alias[$table][$value];
        }
        return($value);
    }


    public function GetFields($table){
        $fields = $this->fields[$table];

        if(isset($this->alias[$table]) === true) {
            $fn = function($e) use ($table) {
                return $this->SetAlias($e, $table);
            };
            $fn = $fn->BindTo($this);
            $fields = array_map( $fn, $fields );
        }

        return('`'.implode($fields, '`, `').'`');
    }
}
```

edit: For your static class:

```
    if(isset(self::$alias[$table]) === true) {
        $fn = function($e) use ($table) {
            return Test::SetAlias($e, $table);
        };
        $fields = array_map( $fn, $fields );
    }
```

(are you sure having everything static makes sense in your design?)

edit: or another one.....

```
class Test {
    public static $fields   = array('parking' => array('parking_id', 'parking_country', 'parking_name'));
    public static $alias    = array();

    private static function SetAlias($value, $table){
        if(isset($table[$value]) === true){
            $value = $value.'` AS `'.$table[$value];
        }
        return($value);
    }

    protected static function getFieldMapper($table) {
        if( !isset(self::$alias[$table]) ) {
            return function($e) { return $e; };
        }

        $table = self::$alias[$table];
        return function($e) use ($table) {
            return Test::SetAlias($e, $table);
        };
    }

    public static function GetFields($table){
        $fields = array_map( self::getFieldMapper($table), self::$fields[$table]);
        return('`'.implode($fields, '`, `').'`');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works. Now if I want to use this in a static context there is a big diffence. (I didn't expect this)

Comment: Can you please change or better: add the class defintion with the static modifiers in your question text?

Comment: Done. Added the static example above.

Comment: Added examples for your static class  ...still not sure if this design makes sense. But maybe it does....

Comment: Danke für deine Zeit!

It works! Thanks!! Yes I know. But it is merely an example to understand the logic and implement it in a bigger whole.